# Function in rep() function

Tags: r, function, rep

Why is

```
rep(message("TEST"),3)
rep(c(message("TEST")),3)

>
TEST
NULL
>
```

not the same as

```
c(message("TEST"),message("TEST"),message("TEST"))

>
TEST
TEST
TEST
NULL
>
```

How do I then get the second result using the `rep()` function?

**EDIT:**

Very "conveniently" we could use:

```
invisible(lapply((rep(c(quote(message("TEST"))),3)),eval))
> 
TEST
TEST
TEST
>
```

Comment: You could use `message(rep("TEST\n", 3))` instead

Comment: I like this. I will use it in my code.

Comment: In addition to the edit, `invisible(replicate(3, message("TEST")))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From `?rep`:

> ‘rep’ replicates the values in ‘x’.

The *value* from `message("TEST")` is NULL.

You can check this with e.g.

```
m <- message("TEST");
m;
#NULL
rep(m, 3);
#NULL
rep(NULL, 3);
#NULL
```

As to your second question, see @docendodiscimus' comment.

Comment: yes, i just realised it. `message` has no return value.